# how can i scrape medium content and get all the h1 nad p tag in strings

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape medium content but was aunable to get all the h1 tag, I was able to get all p-tag all to the end but the h1-tag is missing in between the text

I want to be able to scrape all the content in order of appearance along with all the subheadings in h1 tag

this is what i have done

## import stuff

```
import requests
import bs4
import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image
article_URL = 'https://medium.com/bhavaniravi/build-your-1st-python-web-app-with-flask-b039d11f101c' #@param {type:"string"}
# article_URL = 'https://www.tmz.com/2020/07/29/dr-dre-answers-wife-divorce-petition-prenup/'
response = requests.get(article_URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html')
paragraphs = soup.find_all(['li', 'p', 'strong', 'em'])
title = soup.find(['h1','title']).get_text()
print(title)
txt_list = []
tag_list = []
with open('content2.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(title + '\n\n')
  for p in paragraphs:
        if p.href:
            pass
        else:
            if len(p.get_text()) > 100: # this filters out things that are most likely not part of the core article
#                 print(p.href)
                tag_list.append(p.name)
                txt_list.append(p.get_text())

txt_list2 = []
tag_list2 = []
for i in range(len(txt_list)):
#     if '\n' not in txt_list[i]:
    print(txt_list[i])
#         print(len(txt_list[i]))
#     print(tag_list[i])
    print()
    comp1 = txt_list[i].split()[0:5]
    comp2 = txt_list[i-1].split()[0:5]
    if comp1 == comp2:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: sp4c38 is right... using requests and beautiful soup is by far the best way to do this. Medium.com is difficult to parse because they, in my experience, change their HTML fairly often which makes any XPath targeting highly difficult. Using bs4 is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to add the `h1` tag to your paragraphs list by doing:

```
paragraphs = soup.find_all(['li', 'p', 'strong', 'em', 'h1'])
```

Also `title` should look like that:

```
title = soup.find(['title']).get_text()
```

Now all `h1` are in your paragraphs list. Instead of somehow saving them into another array and puzzling them somehow together again I just would put the `<h1>` tags also in there and later check which tag it is and execute different code for different tags like `<p>` or `<h1>`.

```
import requests
import bs4
import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image

article_URL = 'https://medium.com/bhavaniravi/build-your-1st-python-web-app-with-flask-b039d11f101c' #@param {type:"string"}

response = requests.get(article_URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

paragraphs = soup.find_all(['li', 'p', 'strong', 'em', 'h1'])

title = soup.find(['title']).get_text()
print(title)
tag_list = []
with open('content2.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(title + '\n\n')
  for p in paragraphs:
        if not p.href:
            if len(p.get_text()) > 5:
                tag_list.append(p)

for i in range(len(tag_list)):
    text = tag_list[i].get_text()

    if tag_list[i].name in ["p", "li", "strong", "em"]:
        # Code run when text is in a <p> html tag
        print(f"p: {text}")
    elif tag_list[i].name in ["h1"]:
        # Code run when text is in a <h1> html tag
        print(f"h1: {text}")
```

This will run different code for `<p>` and for the `<h1>` html tags.

Comment: Thanks , but can't i have the header tag in the body of the text, rather being separate

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer. I still put both tags into one array and while iterating over this array run different code for the different tags. I can't help you with using two different arrays but maybe this will help you solve your issue. Best regards!